Is copying bookmark files possible in PhpStorm?
I want to copy bookmark files (more then 1 file in different location) from project 1 to project 2 and with same folder tree (if folder is missing then he should make it recursively).
Is it possible ?

there is no “easy” way to do it from the IDE itself - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-38342.
However, you can refer to a similar thread for details on how to do it manually: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000394030.
